# When using @KafkaListener can I get a reference to the underlying KafkaConsumer as I want to read the endOffsets

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When using `@KafkaListener` can I get a reference to the underlying `KafkaConsumer` as I want to read the `endOffsets`

Comment: Thanks Gary is there a way to get a reference to the listener thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `Consumer<?, ?>` parameter to the listener method.

The consumer is not thread-safe so you should only invoke it on the listener thread.

Requires 2.0 or later; the current release is 2.2.3.